# Which is more efficient Ternary operator or one-line IF?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I'm in the middle of rewriting a python code to nodejs and I'm wondering which is more efficient:

```
a = func1()
a = a ? a : func2()
```

or

```
a = func1()
if (!a) a = func2()
```

Originally, I was writing the first block as:

`a = func1() ? func1() : func2()`

but I think this would ultimately call func1() twice, hence assigning it first to a variable.

**NOTE:** I accidentally posted this on ServerFault. Thanks to cyberx86 (https://serverfault.com/users/86472/cyberx86) for pointing this out and saying performance is negligible. And also making a suggestion:

```
a = func1() || func2()
```

***UPDATE:*** For noob programmers like me, the above line is "short-circuit". Meaning if `func1()` returns *true*, it doesn't need to evaluate the return value of `func2()`

Comment: Performance doesn't matter for something this trivial. `a = func1() || func2()` is the right way to go.

Comment: premature optimization is root of all devil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a = func1() || func2()` should be what you are looking for